# Reset minishift config on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, openshift, minishift

Running minishift on Windows 11 pro, I have set some configs but wish to remove them. Is there any way of resetting the minishift config?

I tried using the delete flag with both -f and --clear-cache, but none of these resets config. I could not find any other subflags for delete either that would help. I tried researching it, but I only found information on how to change the set configs, and not how to delete or reset them.